# how to dock a tabcontrol

Tags: c#

I am beginner in c#. I have some problems with arranging the controls on a winforms. In my project, I took one `tabControl` and gave the property `dock --> fill`. After implementing all the designs, I remembered that my form need `panelHeader` as well as `panelFooter`. when I add them and given property `dock -->top` and `dock --> bottom` respectively, these panels are coming on top of the `tabControl`. I tried to solve this by removing `dock --> fill` to `tabControl` and setting it again. but no use. How to solve this problem? (i dont want to delete `tabControl` and redesign because it took me 4 hours for design).

If this is a waste question then please only comment so that i can delete this question later.

Please Help

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:

Well i handled it by using cut and paste properties.. but what if there are more controls to take care of (if so then it will make the form messy).

Comment: I'm no expert but I do recall having to manually size/position sometimes. So you could, in the form's resize function, set the control's height based on the form's height - panelHeader height - panelFooter height. Then you'd also set the control's top to be panelHeader height.

Comment: so it is not possible through design only.. ok thanks i will try.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do it in the designer; I haven't made a GUI in VS in years. The method I described will do what you want... but it might not be the best way. You'll also have to make sure it's positioned properly on load. you could just call the resize event onload for that... Hopefully somebody more experienced can provide a better answer.

Comment: ok, anyway i got the answer using cut and paste properties. because i have only single control to take care of. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try right click on the control and click "Bring to Front". I remember trying this long before I am not sure that this answer is correct.

Comment: nope not working. BTW thankyou for this info. i dont know this.

Comment: This solution should work. Just use `Send to Back` on anything that is docked on the top/bottom, and `Bring to Front` on anything that is docked to fill

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily set Dock = None for Tabcontrol......... add a TableLayoutPanel with 3 rows in your form. 
1.In First row u can add "panelHeader" and set Dock for it
2.Select TabControl and move it to tablelayout second row set the Dock = Fill
3.In last row add your "panelFooter"

Answer (score -1):

You have to write in your `Designer.cs` page this code

```
this.yuortabcontrol.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

And instead .Fill you write as per blow image in `tabcontrol`

[image: tabcontrol]

Comment: Please don't write *anything* in the `Designer.cs` file, except for secrets you want buried (and buried fast, even from you).